# How do I repeat the particular part of the JSON payload for a given amount of times, with the same data

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365

I have the Json payload in which I am passing the dimensions of the boxes that is used to pack items and then sending it to the third party service to generate the bill, but the number of boxes that will be used is fetched from D365 and based on the number of boxes I need to repeat the particular part of the Json payload.

If my no.of boxes are 3 then my json array should be

Can anybody please let me know how this can be achieved

```
"radSrvcItemDTOList":[
                  {
                     "srvcId":"",
                     "weight":"1.000",
                     "volL":"22",
                     "volW":"17",
                     "volH":"27",
                     "cont":"",
                     "qunt":"1"
} 
{
                      "srvcId":"",
                     "weight":"1.000",
                     "volL":"22",
                     "volW":"17",
                     "volH":"27",
                     "cont":"",
                     "qunt":"1"
}
{
                     "srvcId":"",
                     "weight":"1.000",
                     "volL":"22",
                     "volW":"17",
                     "volH":"27",
                     "cont":"",
                     "qunt":"1"
}
```

Comment: You’ll need to loop for the amount of times and add the object to an array each time.

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can do that means how I can specify the amount of times to for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
how I can do that means how I can specify the amount of times to for each loop
```

Based on the details provided, I am passing json from http trigger body as shown below,

```
{
    "radSrvcItemDTOList":[
                  {
                     "srvcId":"",
                     "weight":"1.000",
                     "volL":"22",
                     "volW":"17",
                     "volH":"27",
                     "cont":"",
                     "qunt":"1"
                  }

],
"radDoneList":"sample",
"radRemovedList":"none",
"boxNum":3
}
```

- I have implemented logic app as shown below to get response as required.
  [image]
- Sending json as mentioned in above format from http request trigger.
- Initialized two variables of type integer to assign value of no of boxes. One will be used to decrease the count in until loop. Another one is used for assigning no of boxes to a variable.
  [image]
- Initialized another variable if type string which is used to append the same json value in loop.
  [image]
- Next used until loop to add same json based on no of boxes.
  Expression:

```
 @equals(variables('noOfBoxes'), int(0))
```

[image]

It will repeat untill the value of no of boxes is zero.

- In for each loop taken input as radSrvcItemDTOList array and composed json as shown below.
  [image]
- Added append variable action to add same json .
  [image]
- Next in until loop, added set variable action to decrease the counter value of no of boxes and then added the current value to another variable boxsNum also.
  Expression:

```
 sub(variables('boxesNum'),1)
```

[image]

- At the sending mail with final json as shown below,

[image]

Received mail as shown below,
[image]
Json Response:

```
{  
"radSrvcItemDTOList":[{"cont":"","qunt":"1","srvcId":"","volH":"27","volL":"22","volW":"17","weight":"1.000"}{"cont":"","qunt":"1","srvcId":"","volH":"27","volL":"22","volW":"17","weight":"1.000"}{"cont":"","qunt":"1","srvcId":"","volH":"27","volL":"22","volW":"17","weight":"1.000"}]  
}
```

Comment: I followed the same steps but i am getting the output like this
 "{\"cont\":\"Artículos para el cuidado del cabello\",\"productIdSAT\":\"53131602\",\"qunt\":\"1\",\"srvcId\":\"PACKETS\",\"volH\":\"22\",\"volL\":\"17.5\",\"volW\":\"27\",\"weight\":

Comment: Have I missed anything?

Comment: I know I am using the string function to fetch the values, but at the end I needs to convert it back to Json

Comment: Check last action from my logic app. I have formed Json as required in send email action.

Comment: I know I am using the string function to fetch the values, but at the end I needs to convert it back to Json. For this comment, I will suggest you post it as a new question.